# moq unit testing in c# web api

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I am tring to test one web api method in asp.net core 2.

Web api

method:

```cs
public IActionResult Delete(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var success = sportsService.DeleteSport(id);

        if (!success)
        {
            return new NotFoundResult();
        }
        return new OkResult();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return new StatusCodeResult(400);
    }
}
```

Unit testing part:

```cs
private Mock<ISportsService> mockService;

[SetUp]
public void Setup()
{
    mockService.SetupSequence(x => x.DeleteSport(It.IsAny<int>())).
        Returns(true). // OkResult();
        Returns(false). // NotFoundResult()
        Throws(new Exception()); //Exception
}
```

Test method looks like this. What I am not clear about with this method is, what the right approach to testing the method is?

```cs
[Test]
public void TestStrategyControllerWithDelete()
{
    var result = controller.Delete(STRAT_ID);
    var okResult = result as ObjectResult;
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, okResult.StatusCode);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, okResult.StatusCode);
    Assert.AreEqual(400, okResult.StatusCode);
}
```

and i am okresult as null ! **and not able to get okResult.StatusCode**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting up your mock to:

- return `true` when it is first called
- return `false` when it is called 2nd time.
- throw `new Exception()` when it is called again.

However, in your test you are only calling it once (`var result = controller.Delete(STRAT_ID);` so your Moq will always return `true`.

Write 3 separate tests, rather than one:

```
[Test]
public void Delete_ReturnsOkResult_IfDeleteSuccess()
{
  const int deleteId = 1234;
  mockService.Setup(x => x.DeleteSport(deleteId)).Returns(true);

  var result = controller.Delete(deleteId);

  Assert.IsInstanceOf<OkResult>(result);
}
```

Unit tests should be independant. They should be able to be run in any order without interfering with one another. However, by configuring a `SetupSequence()` in the `[SetUp]` step you are tying at least 3 of them together and forcing an order to them.

**Edit:** for "and not able to get okResult.StatusCode"* update to question

You are returning an [OKResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.okresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0), [NotFoundResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.notfoundresult?view=aspnetcore-3.0) and [StatusCodeResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.statuscoderesult?view=aspnetcore-3.0). None of these inherit from ObjectResult which is why it is NULL. I've updated my code sample to check for explicit type (`OKResult`), this will need updated for each test case.

If you want to check individual StatusCodes you could case it to a `StatusCodeResult` as all return types can be cast to this.

Comment: alright, so what should i write in [SetUp]
public void Setup()?   if we're already doing  mockService.Setup(x => x.DeleteSport(deleteId)).Returns(true); inside!!,   [setup] and [Test]

Comment: if anyone can explain all three cases ( ok, not found, exception) with example then it will be great. thanks

Comment: @Var the 3 cases will be very similar to the single one that is shown. You'll need to change the `mockService.Setup()` step and the assertion as those are what changes between each test.

Comment: can you please explain " asserts" for Exception? - `Assert.IsInstanceOf(typeof(StatusCodeResult), result);`? is correct? - i would love to check 400 status return or not

Comment: For returning the 400/BadRequest I think the following should work: `Assert.AreEqual(400, (result as StatusCodeResult).StatusCode);`. Alternatively you could return `BadRequestResult` and test for `IsInstanceOf<BadRequestResult>` to keep it consistent with the other return types.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this,

1) Success:

```cs
[Test]
public void Delete_ReturnsOkResult_IfDeleteSuccess()
{
  bool isSucceed = true;
  const int deleteId = 1234;

  this.MockSportService(isSucceed);

  var result = controller.Delete(deleteId);

  var okResult = result as ObjectResult;    
  Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.OK, okResult.StatusCode);
}
```

2) Failure:

```cs
[Test]
public void Delete_ReturnsNotFound_IfIdNotFound()
{
  bool isSucceed = false;
  const int deleteId = 1234;

  this.MockSportService(isSucceed);

  var result = controller.Delete(deleteId);

// Do proper asserts
}
```

3) Exceptions,

```cs
[Test]
public void Delete_ThrowsException_IfIdNotFound()
{
  bool isSucceed = false;
  const int deleteId = 1234;

   mockService.Setup(x => x.DeleteSport(It.IsAny<int>())).
        Throws(new Exception());

  // Act
  var result = controller.Delete(deleteId);

  // Assert
  Assert.True(result is StatusCodeResult); // Asserting that the return type is StatusCodeResult

  // Casting the result as StatusCodeResult object
  var statusCodeResult = result as StatusCodeResult;

  // Asserting the status code
  Assert.AreEqual(400, statusCodeResult.StatusCode);
}
```

And have the common method for mocking for success and failure,

```cs
private void MockSportService(bool isSucceed)
{
mockService.Setup(x => x.DeleteSport(deleteId)).Returns(isSucceed);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, how about the bold text in my question any clue?

Comment: can you please explain " asserts" for Exception?

Comment: @Var - Edited the asserts for an exception. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call controler.Delete(...) method 3 times to have the moq return the different status/exception.

I would suggest having discreet tests for each returned status - one for each status (true/false) and one for the exception.

Comment: See @Fermin answer above - he nailed it